# (Installable) File System Driver, Shell Extension Handler or another approach?

Tags: file-systems, document-management

I have an application that does some document handling as part of its functionality. I would like to implement a "Drive" emulator that would allow users to navigate and manage documents as if they were on a local drive. In my mind, this would be similar to how a remote session can access a local drive. But I'm not sure what the proper approach is. I don't see needing direct access to local hardware, so a driver doesn't seem quite right. But I would like users to see the root drive in File Explorer and to be able to access it in a command window via a drive identifier (i.e. MYAPP:\). File metadata is stored in SQL Azure and the files, themselves, are stored in Azure Blob containers. The folder structure would be defined by the underlying database and would not be alterable by end users. I would want to preserve our current soft delete and history retention, implemented through the application. And users would have to be authenticated.

Thoughts on most appropriate approach?

Comment: A simple solution could be to just use an existing protocol like [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). Or [one of the other hundred or so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Network_file_systems) ...

Comment: You could also expose this as an ftp share. Bonus points you can even automatically add the share as a drive mapping.

Comment: @Kain0_0 - Assuming I can customize the server end of the FTP feed, Is there a way to have this show as a drive in File Explorer?

Comment: A quick search [reveals](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows?)